# What is $\lim_{h→0} \frac {f(2+2h+h^2)−f(2)}{f(1+h−h^2)−f(1)}$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

> lf f(x) is differentiable function and $f′(1)=4,f′(2)=6,f′(c)$ means
>   the derivative of f at c, then $\lim_{h→0} \frac
>  {f(2+2h+h^2)−f(2)}{f(1+h−h^2)−f(1)}$ is?

I cant understand how to approach this problem.I tried applying limits definition of derivative but ended with nothing.Hints anyone?

Answer (score 10):

Write it like $$\frac {f(2+2h+h^2)−f(2)}{f(1+h−h^2)−f(1)} = \frac{f(2+2h+h^2)−f(2)}{h^2 + 2h} \cdot \frac{h - h^2}{f(1+h−h^2)−f(1)} \cdot \frac{h^2 + 2h}{h - h^2}.$$ Each of these three factors has a limit as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Good observation +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Use a Taylor approximation at $2$ and $1$, respectively.
$$
f(2+2h+h^2) = f(2)+f^\prime(2)\cdot(2h) + o(h) = f(2) + 12h + o(h)
$$
and 
$$
f(1+h-h^2) = f(1)+f^\prime(1)\cdot h + o(h) = f(1)+4h+o(h)
$$
so that (put your cursor over to see the rest)

> $$\frac{f(2+2h+h^2)−f(2)}{f(1+h−h^2)−f(1)} = \frac{12h+o(h)}{4h+o(h)} = \frac{3+o(1)}{1+o(1)} \xrightarrow[h\to0]{}3$$

Comment: This is also a good method. +1

Comment: Incidentally, "Taylor approximation" (of order 1, as is the case here) is basically a fancy phrase to say "(local) approximation by an affine function."

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the L'Hôpital rule, then:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(2+2 h+h^2)-f(2)}{f(1+ h-h^2)-f(1)}=
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(2+2 h)\,f'(2+2 h+h^2)}{(1-2 h)\,f'(1+ h-h^2)}=
\frac{2\,f'(2)}{f'(1)}=3$$

Comment: Loved this one :-D

Comment: This requires the derivative $f'$ to be continuous.